# Convert CSV to COCO JSON format for bounding box annotation

Tags: python, json, tensorflow, pytorch, object-detection

I have a `csv` file format for the bounding box annotation.

The format is as below:

```
filename    width   height  class   xmin    ymin    xmax    ymax    image_id
```

Image id is the id that is unique for each image. There are images with multiple objects. Hence multiple rows with same `filename` and `image_id` (one row for each object).

I want to convert the `csv` file to COCO `JSON` file format.

Do you know how I can convert it?

Answer (score -1):

There are a few examples explained online. I recommend [this one](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-convert-tensorflow-object-detection-csv-data-to-coco-json-format-d0693d5b2f75)